# Read strings from ATmega or Arduino

Tags: arduino, atmega, flash, avrdude, security

I have found out that one can disassemble an ATmega with objdump or avrdude. And if the LB1 and LB2 bits are set low it would be much harder. So if these bits are set high or just reading the flash is allowed is it possible to extract the strings that the program may contain.

For example, the strings contained in a compile C program that runs e.g. under Linux can be find out by running "strings a.out".

Is it possible to read the strings from an ATmega similar to the "strings a.out" example?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sry, I have added the question now. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read out the ATmega's binary program, and store it in a file, strings will work.

Often C is used to program ATmega's, and it will store strings in exactly the same way as strings are stored on by C on Linux. They are `'\0'` terminated sequences of bytes, usually ASCII. It is such a useful string format, that people often do the same thing with assembler.

It is *many* years since I looked at the details, but the `strings` program used to work by looking for `'\0'` characters, then reading backwards over plausible ASCII characters.

Comment: Thank you, so reading it with e.g. "avrdude -p m328p -P usb -c usbtiny -U flash:r:flash.bin:r" and then performing strings on the saved bin file should work?

Comment: I'd need to go look at the avrdude options to be certain, but that looks plausible. As long as you have a one-to-one copy of flash, you should be fine.